# Sort Id in access database

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

I have written a VB program that uses an MS Access database. In one the tables, I have set a column named `sampleID` as a type Text. After inserting values into the database it looks like this (which is not sorted correctly).

```
BK130101
BK1301010
BK1301011
BK130108
BK130109
```

I  would like it to sort like this:

```
BK130101
BK130108
BK130109
BK1301010
BK1301011
```

Any idea how to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps something like:

```
SELECT TableX.ID
FROM TableX
ORDER BY Left([ID],6), CInt(Mid([ID],7));
```